# Check Cell Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm trying to produce a simple Excel assessment and have come across a stumbling block.

The 'Candidate' needs to correctly format a cell to 'Currency' so that it shows the £ sign in the cell.

Is there a function that can check the presence of the '£' after the cell has been formatted

The function bar only shows the value as a number without the £ sign

[image: Function Bar Value]

On my scoring sheet, I give a value of '1' for correct answer and '0' for incorrect.

I therefore could really use some advice to help me establish if the 'Candidate' correctly formats the cell

[image]

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Go into the VBE and add an empty module. Copy into that module the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsFormatted(FormattedCell As Range) As Byte

IsFormatted = 0
If InStr(1, FormattedCell.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat, "$", vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then IsFormatted = 1

End Function
```

Then you have the function which you can use like this: `=IsFormatted(D2)`.

Note: the generic number format for currencies is made with a $ sign and not a £. This translates automatically into UK currency based on your windows settings. If you want to make sure that people have set the format of the cell to UK £ then you need to change the following line in the above code:

```
If InStr(1, FormattedCell.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat, "[$£-809]", vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then IsFormatted = 1
```

Please keep in mind that the above function is not `volatile`. That means the value of the function will not change if the referenced cell is changed. In other words: if you check a cell like so `=IsFormatted(D2)` and we assume that this formula is in cell F2 then F2 will be 0 when D2 is not correctly formatted. Now, if you format D2 correctly then F2 will still display 0. So, you'll have to force-update the sheet with the functions with `F9` or you add `Application.Volatile` to the above function. Yet, this may significantly slow down your Excel. Look at the following article for more details: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html

Comment: Hi Ralph, The test sheet is called 'Assessment' does this need to be specified in the VBE code anywhere please

Comment: No, just use the formula. Example: `=IsFormatted(Assesment!B1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a = Right(Left(range("D3").numberformat, 3), 1) to see what format it is in. Based on the string that it pulls, you will be able to find the currency symbol that is showing in the cell.

You could also change the range to a dynamic variable to check any cell that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without VBA and with just an Excel formula, however, there is a caveat that may, or may not, be important to you.

Enter this formula in your scoring sheet.

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",testSheet!D2),1)=",",1,0)
```

1. testSheet is the candidate sheet
2. the `CELL("format",` argument returns `,[decimal places]` for currency formatted cells
3. the `LEFT(...,1)` returns the first letter in the string for number 2
4. the `IF` wrapper says if the first character of the format is `,` then 1, else 0.
5. And here's the **caveat**, the format could be in `£` or `$` or any other symbol, so I don't know if that is necessary to test for or not.

Lastly, you could modify this formula to test for 2 decimal places like so

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",testSheet!D2),2)=",2",1,0)
```

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work on my computer. I get for `=CELL("format", SomeCell)` the return value `C2-`. Could it be that your solution requires a particular language code?

Comment: @Ralph `C2-` is accounting format. Are you testing that the "candidate" clicks the accounting format icon? If so, just change the format return type in the `If` statement. See [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) for more information on the function.

Comment: Strange, I have `currency` selected and not `accounting`. Are they both the same? Also, the referenced cell is correctly formatted showing a `£` but your solution returns `0`. Maybe I should note that UK is not my native language and therefore I had to select the `£` sign explicitly in the number format drop-down (within currencies).

Comment: @Ralph I just did a test. It shows `C2` when I format to `$` (native English), but `,2` when I choose any non-native currency. Maybe that helps you modify it a bit to get it to work for you? Also note that with `CELL` you need to recalc everytime to get it show the new format when a change occurs.